# the use of the word "of" in the sentence

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Could you tell me the grammatical function of the word "of" in the sentence below?

"You're just clearing it of all the filth and just putting it somewhere that's outside of you."

I can guess it means the same as "You're just clearing all the filth..."
But I don't understand why "of" is used in the sentence.

I'd appreciate your explanation of the grammar rule and some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *of* is there because of the *it*. The object of clearing is ‘it’.

If the phrase was ‘clearing all the filth’ the object would be ‘filth’. Seems less precise but which is better depends on the context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me clear the question!